# Is it harmful not to update python

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora

I have fedora 34 and it is asking to update packages and among the packages is python and I don't need it

Does keeping it on the same version cause problems?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't need it

Here's the particular problem: you might not need it, but things that Fedora and the other packages you use, may indeed need it.

So updating it is *generally* a good idea to whatever the current version of Fedora expects, which in this case, according to [the docs](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f33/release-notes/developers/Development_Python/) Fedora 33 expects Python 3.9.